# How to get a list of files matching a cell value in GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm hoping to make (what I hoped was) a very basic script, where you can type part of a document name into a Google Spreadsheet, and underneath will appear the files in your Drive that have that word in their title.

As an example, I have two files in my Drive called "Rome Adventure" and "London Adventure", and the idea would be that if you typed "Rome", "London", or "Adventure" into a cell, the file titles would appear below.

So far I've got this:

```
function onEdit(e){

  // Gets the edited cell, turns it into string

  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var input = range.getCell(1,1).getValue();
  var SearchString = 'title contains "' + input + '"';


  // Searches Drive for files with titles containing whatever you typed
  // and appends titles to the spreadsheet

  var result = DriveApp.searchFiles(SearchString);
  while (result.hasNext()) {
    var file = result.next();
    activeSheet.appendRow([file.getName()]);
  }
}
```

But unfortunately nothing is appended, regardless of what I enter. I've tried "Rome", "London", and just about everything else I can think of. Thinking I might have stuffed up something in the first section, I added

```
range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
```

in between the two sections, and *that* worked. So it's definitely just the DriveApp.searchFiles that I've stuffed up. I thought I might have stuffed up the StringSearch bit, but changing the line to

```
var result = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "Rome"');
```

still doesn't return anything.

I'm only an enthusiast-level programmer, and this is the first time I've asked a question on here. So forgive me if this is a stupid question, or it's not possible. I'm just at my wit's end trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your function. It's failing because of an undocumented restriction using the `onEdit` trigger to search DriveApp. If you run the script as is and then go to View > Execution transcript, you'll see the failure message at the bottom.

You can call the function successfully from a custom menu. Instead of watching for the edited row, use `.getActiveCell()`. It will search the string inside the selected cell on the spreadsheet. A working example is below.

```js
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Search").addItem("Run", "searchFiles").addToUi();
}

function searchFiles() {
  var string = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue();
  var result = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "' + string + '"');

  while (result.hasNext()) {
    var file = result.next();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().appendRow([file.getName()]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Brian, you are a lifesaver! That works perfectly!! Thank you.

Would it be possible to use the onEdit Trigger to call the searchFiles function you wrote? Or is there no way to search DriveApp with that trigger?